# Postfix warning: hostname [unknown host] does not resolve to address [unknown ip]

Tags: postfix

I've seen a couple other questions with this error message but it seemed that the host and ip in question were ones the OP knew. These two are unrelated to my server.

Where and why is postfix generating this error?

> Jul 24 17:42:14 email postfix/smtpd[32277]: warning: hostname kimtake.respectedopinion.com does not resolve to address 62.210.28.114
>   Jul 24 17:42:14 email postfix/smtpd[32277]: connect from unknown[62.210.28.114]
>   Jul 24 17:42:14 email postfix/smtpd[32277]: disconnect from unknown[62.210.28.114]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the IP address points to the host, but the host points to a different IP. Previously I had only looked up the host's IP

`host 62.210.28.114` => `kimtake.respectedopinion.com`

`host kimtake.respectedopinion.com` => `67.227.26.69`

Feel free to comment or answer if you have a better explanation of why this would happen

Comment: It's exactly that!